How to reflect over multiple objects in Kotlin to find properties of a specific type
I know how to reflect and iterate over the properties of a single object in Kotlin to find all properties of specific type:
object Obj1{
    val obj1Int = 1
    val obj1String = "one"
}

fun main(){
    // filter out the integer property, keep the string property
    Obj1::class
        .declaredMemberProperties
        .mapNotNull { it.get(Obj1) as? String }
        .forEach { println(it) }  // prints "one", does not print "1"
}

but I'm having trouble getting this to work when I have a list of generic objects:
object Obj1{
    val obj1Int = 1
    val obj1String = "one"
}

object Obj2{
    val obj2Int = 2
    val obj2String = "two"
}

fun main() {
    listOf(Obj1, Obj2).forEach {obj ->
        obj::class.declaredMemberProperties
            .mapNotNull { it.get(obj) as? String } // compiler error
            .forEach { println(it) }

    }
}

The it.get(obj) has an error: Type mismatch: inferred type is Any but Nothing was expected
How would I do this?

This is happening because the compiler doesn't understand you get a property value from exactly the same object as the one you acquired properties for. It doesn't track you used obj in both places. As such, it doesn't allow this operation, because it is not sure obj has the required property.
As we know obj is guaranteed to have the property, and the code is safe, we can cast the property. This will be an unchecked cast:
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
(it as KProperty1<Any, *>).get(obj) as? String

Your first example is different, because you acquired properties from a very specific type Obj1 and the compiler can verify you then use the same Obj1 to get values.
